# How can I go about creating articulated threads over a set of wheels

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-view

I have the following wheels:

[image]

How can I create threads that are articulate at two points like:

https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-edac31b22e3365b0755773541d594c2f

.blend attached.

I've read about Bezier curves but that doesn't solve the articulation point between two adjacent plates.

[image]

Comment: I know there is a YouTube video I saw for a garage door that he also modified for a tank tread but they don't like linking to youtube videos here... basically it was a bezier curve with an animated empty and you put the empty in front of the tread and use a damped track to start it making the pivot turn. Repeat down the line of tread plates.

Comment: I found that one but I need some hotkeys for separating vetexes in a curve (disjoint)